# Unable to find local resource XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

In my user control `XAML` I am trying to use an `IValueConverter` .. I have a class named `NullToBoolConverter` which implements `IValueConverter`.

I define my namespace like this:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
```

In my `UserControl.Resources`, I am trying to reference this class, like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:NullToBoolConverter x:Key="IsNull"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

When I start to type in the name of the class `NullToBoolConverter`, *it appears in the drop down menu in the list of available local classes*, but as soon as I select it I get the message: `The name "NullToBoolConverter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyApp".`

Am I doing something wrong here ? Any help is appreciated ..

Comment: How did you define the namespace?

Comment: Are you sure the namespace is correct?

Comment: I defined the namespace like this: xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp" ... I would assume this is correct as the list of classes that appears when I type 'local:' is correct ..

Comment: I would also be interested in knowing why this has been down voted, and how the question could be improved. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes Xaml does it like this. Just try to compile the application once , your error might go away after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@srsyogesh was right in the comments, however I had to actual restart vs 2012 to resolve this issue.